# iPhone Presenting modal view from UITextField using segues?

Tags: iphone, uitextfield, presentmodalviewcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

As title states it, i am using iOS5 feature storyboards. I have a text field, which when tapped should display modal view (with picker). I was wondering can this action be triggered using segues?

When you have button or cell you just ctrl drag to view controller that you want to present. I have done same with text field but with no visible results. I just press it and and only keyboard pops. No modal view showing. What should I do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are some thoughts to your questions, I hope that they can be helpful:

- If your `viewController` adopts `UITextFieldDelegate`, then you can implement the optional delegate method `textFieldDidBeginEditing:`, and get notified when the `textField` becomes first responder and do what you want to do, e.g. presenting a modal view controller ([UITextFieldDelegate Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html)). However, when the `textField` becomes first responder and keyboard pops out, at the same time you will be popping out a modal view too, that doesn't sound very user-friendly.
- If user has only limited choices to pick from, why using a `textField`?
- The other alternative could be implementing `textFieldShouldBeginEditing:` (again, you need to adopt `UITextFieldDelegate`). Per Apple,

> When the user performs an action that would normally initiate an
>   editing session, the text field calls this method first to see if
>   editing should actually proceed. In most circumstances, you would
>   simply return YES from this method to allow editing to proceed.

You will `return NO` so that the keyboard won't pop, and instead pop your modal view controller. You do this by first calling `presentViewController:animated:completion:` and then returning NO ([UIViewController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)) -- I haven't tested this, but it sounds it should work.

- I am not 100% sure. I think I heard it somewhere that `segue`s in storyboard are invoked with `UIControlEvent` equivalent of `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` -- think of `UIButton` (I might be wrong), but if this is true, when `UITextField` becomes first responder, that is not the control event, therefore the `segue` won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Weeel, textFieldShouldBeginEditing: approach works well on ios8

however it does not work consistently on ios7

I have ended setting textfield.enabled = NO 
and overlaying the uitextfield with a transparent uibutton
to tigger a VC presentation